Possible gcc bug with type alias and templates
I was working with templated type aliases and I came across what seems to me like a bug.
You can play with the code here (Compiler Explorer)
I Can't really think about anything wrong with the code and it does work on the latest clang.
template <auto L, auto L2>
struct S
{
    static constexpr auto l = L;
    static constexpr auto l2 = L2;
};

template<auto L>
using alias1 = S<L, []{return "hello";}>;

template<typename I>
using alias2 = alias1<[]{return "World";}>;

using A = alias2<int>;  // Not working with template

using no_template = alias1<[]{return "World";}>;

using A2 = no_template; // Working without template

and the compilation error is error: 'alias2' does not name a type; did you mean 'alias1'?
Should I report this? Or am I missing something in the standard that doesn't allow to do something like this?

I believe you are correct, this should compile. And it does with MSVC and Clang. I've also tried using A = ::alias2<int>;, but that just changes the error message (does not name a template instead of does not name a type). Funnily enough, defining template<typename I> using alias3 = S<[]{return "World";}, []{return "hello";}>; and then doing using A = alias3<int>; will work -- and I don't see a reason why the additional level of indirection should be a problem. That said: I don't know the standard well enough to be 100% sure.

Changing lambda to regular int makes gcc happy... Demo. It seems really to be a gcc bug.

It is a known GCC issue: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92707
